# DHCP C++ Program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dhcp

So I have been looking around found some code to which was from MS site [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and have pieced together what seems to be a working way to grab the dhcp information by option that I am looking to obtain as you will see in the code. But for some reason the only thing I receive back from my methods is either zero or nothing. I was wondering if anyone had any insight.

**CODE:**

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "WINDOWS.H"
#include "Dhcpcsdk.h"
//#include "Dhcpcsvc.dll"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment( lib, "dhcpcsvc.lib" )

#define NUMBER_OF_OPTIONS 7


//#define NUMBER_OF_OPTIONS 4
enum OptionArrayPositions
{
   MASK,
   DNS,
   HOSTNAME,
   VENDOR,
   LEASE_TIME,
   MESSAGE_TYPE,
   SERVERIP
};

BOOL RetrieveDHCPInfo(LPWSTR pszAdapterName);
void PrintAsAscii(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param);
void PrintAsIP(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param);
void PrintAsInt(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param);
void PrintMask(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param);
void PrintDNS(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param);
void PrintHostName(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param);
void PrintVendor(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param);
void PrintLeaseTime(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param);
void PrintMessageType(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param);
void PrintServerIP(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param);
void Printer(char[500]);

BOOL RetrieveDHCPInfo(LPWSTR pszAdapterName)
{
   DWORD dwError, dwSize;
   CHAR TmpBuffer[1000]; // host name won't be larger than this


   DHCPCAPI_PARAMS DhcpApiMaskParams = {0,
                                    OPTION_SUBNET_MASK,
                                    FALSE,
                                    NULL,
                                    0
                                    };
   DHCPCAPI_PARAMS DhcpApiDNSParams = {0,
                                    OPTION_DOMAIN_NAME_SERVERS,
                                    FALSE,
                                    NULL,
                                    0
                                    };
   DHCPCAPI_PARAMS DhcpApiHostNameParams = {0,                // Flags
                                       OPTION_HOST_NAME, // OptionId
                                       FALSE,            // vendor specific?
                                       NULL,             // data filled in on return
                                       0                 // nBytes
                                       }; 
   DHCPCAPI_PARAMS DhcpApiVendorParams = {0,
                                       OPTION_VENDOR_SPEC_INFO,
                                       FALSE,
                                       NULL,
                                       0
                                    };
   DHCPCAPI_PARAMS DhcpApiLeaseTimeParams = {0,
                                          OPTION_LEASE_TIME,
                                          FALSE,
                                          NULL,
                                          0
                                       };    
   DHCPCAPI_PARAMS DhcpApiMsgTypeParams = {0,
                                       OPTION_MESSAGE_TYPE,
                                       FALSE,
                                       NULL,
                                       0
                                       };

   DHCPCAPI_PARAMS DhcpApiServerNameParams = {0,
                                          OPTION_SERVER_IDENTIFIER,
                                          FALSE,
                                          NULL,
                                          0
                                          };

   DHCPCAPI_PARAMS paramArray[NUMBER_OF_OPTIONS] = { DhcpApiMaskParams, 
                                                DhcpApiDNSParams,
                                                DhcpApiHostNameParams, 
                                                DhcpApiVendorParams, 
                                                DhcpApiLeaseTimeParams,
                                                DhcpApiMsgTypeParams,
                                                DhcpApiServerNameParams
                                                };

   DHCPCAPI_PARAMS_ARRAY DhcpApiParamsArray = {NUMBER_OF_OPTIONS,  // only one option to request
                                          paramArray
                                          };
   DHCPCAPI_PARAMS_ARRAY SendParams = {0, NULL};

   dwSize = sizeof(TmpBuffer);
   dwError = DhcpRequestParams(DHCPCAPI_REQUEST_SYNCHRONOUS, // Flags
                           NULL,                         // Reserved
                           pszAdapterName,               // Adapter Name
                           NULL,                         // not using class id
                           SendParams,                   // nothing to send
                           DhcpApiParamsArray,           // requesting params
                           (PBYTE) TmpBuffer,            // buffer
                           &dwSize,                      // buffer size
                           NULL                          // Request ID
                           );

   cout << "Your Error Code from DhcpRequestParams is " << dwError << endl;
   if( ERROR_MORE_DATA == dwError ) 
   {
      //
      // dwSize is not large enough.
       cout<<"dwSize is not large enough"<<endl;
      //
   }

   int success = FALSE;
   if( NO_ERROR == dwError ) 
   {
      for(int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_OPTIONS; i++)
      {
         if(paramArray[i].nBytesData != 0)
         {
            success = true;
            switch(paramArray[i].OptionId)
            {
               case OPTION_SUBNET_MASK:
                  PrintMask(paramArray[i]);
                  break;
               case OPTION_DOMAIN_NAME_SERVERS:
                  PrintDNS(paramArray[i]);
                  break;
               case OPTION_HOST_NAME:
                  PrintHostName(paramArray[i]);
                  break;
               case OPTION_VENDOR_SPEC_INFO:
                  PrintVendor(paramArray[i]);
                  break;
               case OPTION_LEASE_TIME:
                  PrintLeaseTime(paramArray[i]);
                  break;
               case OPTION_MESSAGE_TYPE:
                  PrintMessageType(paramArray[i]);
                  break;
               case OPTION_SERVER_IDENTIFIER:
                  PrintServerIP(paramArray[i]);
                  break;
            }
         }
      }
      cout << endl;
   }

   if(success == TRUE)
      return TRUE;
   else
      return FALSE;
}

void PrintAsAscii(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param)
{
   unsigned char temp[260];
   CopyMemory(temp, 
   param.Data,
   param.nBytesData);

   temp[param.nBytesData] = '\0';
   cout << temp;
}

void PrintAsIP(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param)
{
   unsigned char temp[260];
   CopyMemory(temp, 
   param.Data,
   param.nBytesData);

   temp[param.nBytesData] = '\0';
   for(unsigned int i=0; i<param.nBytesData; i++)
   { 
      if(i%4 == 0)
      {
         cout << endl;
      }
         cout << (int)temp[i]<< ".";
   }
}

void PrintAsInt(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param)
{
   unsigned char temp[260];
   CopyMemory(temp, 
   param.Data,
   param.nBytesData);

   temp[param.nBytesData] = '\0';
   cout << (unsigned int)*temp;
}

void PrintMask(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param)
{
   /* Print the subnet mask
   * This is stored as Option 1
   *
   *
   */
   cout << endl << "MASK" << endl;
   cout << "--------------------------------------------";
   PrintAsIP(param);
}

void PrintDNS(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param)
{
   /* Print the DNS Servers
   * This is stored as Option 6
   *
   *
   */
   cout << endl << "\nDNS SERVERS" << endl;
   cout << "--------------------------------------------";
   PrintAsIP(param);
}

void PrintHostName(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param)
{
   /* Print the Host name or IP address if 
   * that's what's stored in this option
   * This is stored as Option 12
   *
   */
   cout << endl << "\nHOST NAME" << endl;
   cout << "--------------------------------------------";
   cout << endl << "ANSI String" << endl;
   PrintAsAscii(param);
   cout << endl << "IP FORMAT";
   PrintAsIP(param);
}

void PrintVendor(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param)
{
   /* Print the Vendor parameter
   * This is stored as Option 43
   *
   *
   */
   cout << endl << "\nVENDOR PARAMETER" << endl;
   cout << "--------------------------------------------";
   cout << endl << "ANSI String" << endl;
   PrintAsAscii(param);
}

void PrintLeaseTime(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param)
{
   /* Print the Lease Time
   * This is stored as Option 51
   *
   *
   */
   cout << endl << "\nLEASE TIME" << endl;
   cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;
   PrintAsInt(param);
   cout << endl;
}

void PrintMessageType(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param)
{
   /* Print the message type
   * This is stored as Option 53
   *
   *
   */
   cout << endl << "\nMESSAGE TYPE" << endl;
   cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;;
   PrintAsInt(param);
}

void PrintServerIP(DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param)
{
   /* Print the DHCP servers IP address
   * This is stored as Option 54
   *
   *
   */
   cout << endl << "\nDHCP SERVER" << endl;
   cout << "--------------------------------------------";
   PrintAsIP(param);
} 
void Printer(char input[500]){
    cout << input << endl;
}






int main(){

    struct DHCPAPI_PARAMS {
    ULONG  Flags;
    ULONG  OptionId;
    BOOL   IsVendor;
    LPBYTE Data;
    DWORD  nBytesData;
    };
    /*
    DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param;
    param.Flags = 0;
    param.OptionId = 43;
    param.IsVendor = true;
    //param.Data
    PrintAsIP(param);
    */
    DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param = {0,
                             0,
                             FALSE,
                             NULL,
                             0
                              };


    int x = 1;
    char name[26];char hold[26];
    while(x !=0){
    //cout<<"Hello World"<< endl;
    //cin>>name;    
    cin>>x;
    param.OptionId = x;
    PrintMessageType(param);
    PrintServerIP(param);
    PrintLeaseTime(param);
    PrintVendor(param);
    PrintDNS(param);
    Printer("\n\nEnter New Value:");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The output for a simple run is as follows.

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

EDIT:

I miss understood the use of the begging implementation I had been trying to use, I apologize, the main should look more like this, at least in regards to what should be used.

```
int main(){

    //should be using this but not sure how to declare/find my AdapterName or what
    //should go there for the current controller to which to make the dhcp calls 
    //from the client with. 
    RetrieveDHCPInfo(LPWSTR pszAdapterName);


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your `params` is initialised to all zeros, so the output will be too

Comment: The point is to use DhcpRequestParams provided a DHCPCAPI_PARAMS with an option with it, therefore yielding a result with those functions. the option is not set to zero in my DHCPCAPI_PARAMS param below to use those functions.

Comment: Ok, but `RetrieveDHCPInfo` is not called in your program. Where is `DHCPCAPI_PARAMS` defined, and why do you redefine it inside `main`.

Comment: Ohhh okay, wow I wasn't thinking this right, your first comment is right so I have to initialize RetrieveDHCPInfo(LPWSTR pszAdapterName) correct, I'm sorry I used that MS document to write some stuff and had been on the MS forms where kids had implemented RetrieveDHCPInfo(LPWSTR pszAdapterName) Bool code, and I was honestly just having a hard time understanding how to implement that, if you have better insight I'd appreciate it but your right, my main should not look the way it does. So how do I find LPWSTR pszAdapterName, how do I get my adapters name? Thank you.

Comment: See `GetAdaptersInfo` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: YOUR A LIFE SAVER THANK YOU SO MUCH! I'm not as well versed in c++ as I am java and C# so this would have taken me so much longer to wrap my head around, it's been awhile, thank you very much I have everything working now.

Comment: I'll write up an answer so it can be accepted and the question marks as Answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the points that answered the question:

1. `params` is initialized to all zeros, so the output will be too
2. `RetrieveDHCPInfo()` is not called in the program. Where is `DHCPCAPI_PARAMS` defined, and why do you redefine it inside `main`?
3. To get the adapter name, see `GetAdaptersInfo()` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917(v=vs.85).aspx